# How do I get REST API many to many to one to many information?

Tags: rest, api, design-patterns, many-to-many, restful-url

I have a question about how to design a certain part of my REST API. Imagine the following situation:

*A racing driver can be part of multiple racing teams (i.e. one for Sundays, one for Saturdays, one for rally cross etc.). Every racing team has multiple cars, cars which can only belong to one team. Now, I want my REST API to return a list of all racing cars of every team the driver is part of.*

At the moment, I have the following:

**Drivers**

All drivers: `/drivers`

Certain driver: `/drivers/12345`

Teams a driver is part of: `/drivers/12345/teams`

**Teams**

All teams: `/teams`

Certain team: `/teams/12345`

Cars of a certain team: `/teams/12345/cars`

**Cars**

All cars: `/cars`

Certain car `/cars/12345`

So now, my question is: what is a proper way to define an URL for getting all cars from all the teams a certain driver is part of?

Answer (score 1):

> So now, my question is: what is a proper way to define an URL for getting all cars from all the teams a certain driver is part of?

There is no *proper* way to define a URL, any process that results in a spelling consistent with [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) is fine.

Choosing a URI is a lot like choosing a variable name; the semantics of the spelling don't matter, so you can do whatever makes sense in your local context.

```
/drivers/12345/cars
```

might be a reasonable choice in your situation, and looks reasonably consistent with the other spellings you have already chosen.